# Ubuntu 16.04 network install won't boot

Tags: boot, system-installation

So, I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to a USB using the network installer. I'm no Linux expert, but I know my way around Ubuntu a little bit. My intention is to install the base system only, then build my own spin of Ubuntu from the command line. The problem is, once the installer is finished and I reboot the machine, it just rests on a black screen with a flashing cursor, never reaching the command line. I've retried the installation process repeatedly, but the outcome is always the same. I guess my question is, what is the proper way to go about building a custom Ubuntu distribution from scratch?

Comment: Do you mean that you used an Ubuntu **mini.iso** file to install a base system? In that case, at the flashing cursor, you can try the following hotkey combinations: `ctrl + alt + F2` and maybe again `ctrl + alt + F1` to activate the terminal and get text on the screen. An alternative is to start from an **Ubuntu Server** iso file, which is more polished and tested. You can get almost the same system that way (installed desktop systems, not only Ubuntu Server).

Comment: Or maybe there are problems with the graphics. In that case you had better try a boot option. Start with `nomodeset` according to this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: Yes, I did use the Ubuntu mini.iso file, and installed the base system with no frills. The keyboard hotkeys you supplied work like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, and good luck exploring how to get a good custom system with *your* favourite program packages :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed basic systems (alias minimal systems with text mode interface) made from an Ubuntu **mini.iso** file can have problems displaying the text. I know that this can happen with Intel graphics. It may affect computers with other graphics chips/cards too.

The following hotkey combinations can help to activate the terminal and get text on the screen:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>  and maybe after that <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>